# assigning user defined name while downloading the pdf using itextsharp

Tags: c#, api, itext

when I am downloading a pdf the file name is coming as "**Response**" while saving in the particular location and if I am changing the name of the file then it is coming as the image below.

[image]

and when I am selecting the same default name then its coming perfect.

[image]

is it possible it set the name as user defined.
Code what I am using is:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=filename.pdf");
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

HtmlTextWriter w = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
string pdfFilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(".") + "/PDFFiles";

HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(doc);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);

doc.Open();
try
{
    doc.Add(new Paragraph("Test PDF Download"));
    doc.Close();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(doc);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{ }
finally
{
    doc.Close();
}
```

Comment: First of all, and it has no relation to your question: you use `HTMLWorker`, which is deprecated for years. You should use `XMLWorker` instead (or iText 7 + pdfHTML, but that's a bigger migration effort). Secondly, I don't think your issue has anything to do with the iText part of your code. I think that your operating system is hiding file extensions and when you change the file name, the extension `.pdf` is not added. Try typing the file extension when you save to a custom location. Also, configure your file manager (Windows Explorer?) not to hide extensions.

Comment: This does not look like a programming question to me, but a Windows question. I could be wrong, but then the question needs to give more details.

Comment: You define the file name yourself here: `AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=filename.pdf");` if the filename is coming as `Response` instead as of `filename.pdf`, then there's something wrong with your browser. Which browsers have you tried? MSIE? Edge? Firefox? Chrome? Do they all show the wrong behavior?

Comment: Hello,
The issue mentioned above is coming only when I a testing through Postman. Otherwise its working fine

Comment: My new query is... how to open the pdf in new tab insted of downloading it.
I replaced the attachment to inline which is working,but its opening the pdf in the same tab.